# supremum of the set $\bigl\{ a^{1/n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \bigr \}=1$, where $0<a<1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Clearly, $1$ is an upper bound for the set. I assume that the supremum, denoted by "$x$", is smaller than $1$. Then $x^n$ gets smaller as $n$ increases, so there must be a natural number $N$ such that $x^N<a$, showing that $x$ is not an upper bound and contradiction. My question is that how can I put this idea into a rigorous form, I thought that I can use the Archimedean property but could not find a way.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter According to the title, we must find supermum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the set $X=\{a^\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Then, you can easily verify that if $1\le\epsilon$, then $\epsilon$ is upper bound of $X$. So, $M=\sup X\le1$.

And if $\epsilon<1$, then you can easily verify that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\epsilon^n=0$, and by defenition of limit, you can find natural number $N$ such that $n\ge N\Rightarrow\epsilon^n<a$. Then, $\epsilon<a^\frac1N$, so $\epsilon$ cannot be upper bound of $X$. So $M\ge1$.

Then, $M=1$, which says $\sup X=1$.